# Google Safe Search in WebView

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

Is there a query param, or something that I can enable Safe Search in Webview. 
Actually I have browser and I want that Google.com search results filter by [safe search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/510?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en).

Is safe search feature of google.com search site or the applications like chrome? Please clear.

Comment: is this same question you asked 3 months ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307138/how-to-enable-safe-search-in-my-android-browser

Comment: Hi Nilesh, yes it may be quite similar to my old question. But I have another queries too. Also I tagged google-chrome and google-app-engine, so let them clear me if this is possible while browsing.