# Android Studio Web view can#t load url "server.pro"

Tags: android, webview

Im making a app with android studio for starting my minecraft server which i have hosted at server.pro, the application can load every website like amazon or google but server.pro cant get load into this web view, does anybody know how to fix that?

here is my code from the java file:

```
package com.example.serverpro;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.server.pro");



    }
}
```

Comment: What you are getting as an error?

Comment: E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(549)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
E/cr_PlatformSer-Internal: Unable to determine Safe Browsing user opt-in preference
E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(549)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(19)] "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of null", source: https://server.pro/s/js/vendor.769f0e86bba286d238d6.js (19)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'theme' of null", source: https://server.pro/s/js/app.3b6a8c32e7134172d1d9.js (1)

Comment: I think you should try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/52418845/1318946